# Error: could not find function "makeLearner" using h2o package

Tags: r, h2o, mlr

I'm using `h2o` package and trying to create a learner using the below given code

```
install.packages("h2o")
library("h2o")
h2o.learner <- makeLearner("regr.h2o.deeplearning",predict.type = "response")
```

But I'm getting this error

```
> h2o.learner <- makeLearner("regr.h2o.deeplearning",predict.type = "response")
Error: could not find function "makeLearner"
```

**Note**: Few months back I used this code without any problem.

Any idea what could be possible thing for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code for this is simply

```
library(mlr)
h2o.learner = makeLearner("regr.h2o.deeplearning")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `makeLearner()` is not part of H2O. It appears to be part of the [mlr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/vignettes/mlr.html). It also seems that mlr does have h2o support, so it might be as simple as adding a `library(mlr)` to the top of your script?  (Making sure that the mlr package has been installed, already, of course.)